# Open a URL + the text input by the user using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have input box and a submit button.

1. The user will input their "reference number" (example: "hello123")
2. user will click the submit button.
3. after clicking the submit button, the javascript will open url link
   in a New browser Tab with a url link (which i assigned) plus the
   input of the user (which is hello123)

Assigned url is (for example): www.mywebsite.com/ after clicking the submit button, the url to open by javascript is: www.mywebsite.com/print/hello123/

i have this code:

```
<input type="text" id="text" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" onClick="javascript: window.open('http://www.mywebsite.com/print/' + document.getElementById('text').value);" />
```

but it's really not working. any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We form the new URL as follows:

`var url = "www.mywebsite.com/"+document.getElementById('text').value;`

In the onclick event, change it to :

`window.location=url;`

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery is the simplest way to do this

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
    window.location="www.yourwebsite.com/url/here/"+$("#text").val();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `window.open` with `window.location`.

Also if you are already on **www.mywebsite.com** just write

`window.location.href=document.getElementById('text').value`.

Comment: it is an external website. will try your approach.